# Accessing iPhone device hardware through safari browser?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, cordova

I am developing an iPhone application using phonegap and accessing device hardware through objective C plug-ins. It works fine. But I want to host phonegap iphone application on webserver and to access through safari browser in iphone? Is it possible to access device hardware like camera,etc by accessing phonegap application in browser? Any help please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it is not possible. Javascript code running in Safari will not get the kind of privileges that you can get by using your own `UIWebView` in a native application.